# Why is my UserControl not being loaded in my MainWindow?

Tags: c#, avaloniaui, avalonia

I am trying to set up my application to show a different view depending on what the name of the device is. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get the View to load, though the ViewModel is getting called. I'm not entirely sure what I'm missing.

Currently, when the application loads, the only thing shows up is the MainWindow, but the View is not being loaded inside of it.

How can I get a View to load?

Here is my MainWindow.axaml:

```
<Window
    xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TAStagingApp.ViewModels.Implementations;assembly=TAStagingApp.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignWidth="800"
    d:DesignHeight="450"
    x:Class="TAStagingApp.Views.MainWindow"
    x:DataType="vm:MainWindowViewModel"
    Background="{StaticResource TABackgroundColor}"
    Icon="/Assets/tastaging.png"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Title="TA Staging">

    <Design.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Design.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ContentPresenter Name="StagingContent"/>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

And the MainWindow.axaml.cs

```
namespace TAStagingApp.Views;
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public void SetContent(Control control)
    {
        var mainContent = this.FindControl<ContentPresenter>("StagingContent");
        mainContent!.Content = control;
    }
}
```

App.axaml.cs

```
using AvaloniaApplication = Avalonia.Application;

namespace TAStagingApp;
public partial class App : AvaloniaApplication
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        AvaloniaXamlLoader.Load(this);
    }

    public override void OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted()
    {
        var viewModelLoader = new ViewModelLoader(new MainWindow());
        ServiceLocator.Initialize(viewModelLoader);

        if (ApplicationLifetime is IClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetime desktop)
        {
            DataContext = GetRequiredService<IMainWindowViewModel>();
            desktop.MainWindow = new MainWindow
            {
                DataContext = DataContext,
            };

            viewModelLoader.LoadContentViewBasedOnComputerName();
        }

        base.OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted();
    }

    private static T GetRequiredService<T>() => Locator.Current.GetRequiredService<T>();
}
```

ViewModelLoader.cs

```
namespace TAStagingApp.DependencyInjection.Loaders;
public sealed class ViewModelLoader(MainWindow mainWindow) : IViewModelLoader
{
    private readonly MainWindow _mainWindow = mainWindow;

    public void LoadContentViewBasedOnComputerName()
    {
        var serviceProvider = DeviceTypeHelper.GetDeviceTypeServiceProvider();
        var deviceType = DeviceTypeHelper.GetDeviceType(serviceProvider);

        Control contentView = deviceType.Value.ToString() switch
        {
            var device when device.Equals(DeviceType.Server.ToString()) => new ServerConfigureView(),
            var device when device.Equals(DeviceType.Terminal.ToString()) => new TerminalConfigureView(),
            var device when device.Equals(DeviceType.Kitchen.ToString()) => new TerminalConfigureView(),
            _ => new AdminView()
        };

        _mainWindow.SetContent(contentView);
    }
}
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
namespace TAStagingApp.ViewModels.Implementations;

public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase, IMainWindowViewModel
{
    public MainWindowViewModel(IActivateViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (viewModel.GetType() == typeof(TerminalConfigureViewModel))
        {
            TerminalConfigureViewModel = viewModel;
        }
        else if (viewModel.GetType() == typeof(ServerConfigureViewModel))
        {
            ServerConfigureViewModel = viewModel;
        }
        else
        {
            AdminViewModel = viewModel;
        }

        Activate(viewModel);
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
    }

    public IActivateViewModel AdminViewModel { get; } = default!;

    public IActivateViewModel TerminalConfigureViewModel { get; } = default!;

    public IActivateViewModel ServerConfigureViewModel { get; } = default!;

    private static void Activate(IActivateViewModel viewModel)
        => viewModel.Activate();
}
```

I've been looking at this for two days now and can't figure out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `ViewModelLoader` is working with an instance of `MainWindow` which is different from the actual

```cs
public override void OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted()
{
    var viewModelLoader = new ViewModelLoader(new MainWindow()); // <<<< this window 
    ServiceLocator.Initialize(viewModelLoader);

    if (ApplicationLifetime is IClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetime desktop)
    {
        DataContext = GetRequiredService<IMainWindowViewModel>();
        desktop.MainWindow = new MainWindow // <<< diffrent from this window
        {
            DataContext = DataContext,
        };

        viewModelLoader.LoadContentViewBasedOnComputerName();
    }

    base.OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted();
}
```

you can fix it by instantiating `ViewModelLoader` with the application Main window

```
public override void OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted()
{
    if (ApplicationLifetime is IClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetime desktop)
    {
        DataContext = GetRequiredService<IMainWindowViewModel>();
        desktop.MainWindow = new MainWindow
        {
            DataContext = DataContext,
        };

        // <<< instantiate ViewModelLoader with the application MainWindow
        var viewModelLoader = new ViewModelLoader(desktop.MainWindow);
        ServiceLocator.Initialize(viewModelLoader);

        viewModelLoader.LoadContentViewBasedOnComputerName();
    }

    base.OnFrameworkInitializationCompleted();
}
```

#### Side Advice

Actually, you should redesign your architecture because you get architecture dead look!

If I were you, I will use [data templates](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/templates/data-templates) to make my life easy!

```xml
 <Window.DataTemplates>
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ServerConfigureViewModel}">
     <view:ServerConfigureView/>      
   </DataTemplate>

   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TerminalConfigureViewModel}">
     <view:TerminalConfigureView/>
   </DataTemplate>

   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:AdminViewModel}">
     <view:AdminView/>
   </DataTemplate>
 </Window.DataTemplates>
```

And put in your `MainViewModle` Property Called `CurrentViewModel` or `ActivatedViewModel` or Whatever of type `ViewModelBase`

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ViewModelBase _currentViewModel;

    public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModdel
    {
        get => _currentViewModel;
        set => SetProperty(ref _currentViewModel, value);
    }

}
```

All of `ServerConfigureViewModel`, `TerminalConfigureViewModel` and `AdminViewModel` should inherit from `ViewModelBase` and can be signed to `CurrentViewModdel`

and bind to it in main Window

```xml
<Grid>
  <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"/>
</Grid>
```

now if you change `CurrentViewModdel` in Main Window View will change without all this code of `ViewModleLocator` and this staff

Comment: That did it! Thanks. I knew it was gong to be something simple.

Comment: @Harlan Happy to help... you are welcome :)

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on using the data templates? What would my MainWindowViewModel look like? I tried making those changes, but they weren't working. I did modify my MainWindow.axaml and the App.axaml.cs as well. I also wasn't sure where to move the call to the Activate method on my ViewModels. I'm assuming the constructor. It would be nice not to have the extra code.

Comment: @Harlan yep sure [refer to My Repo in Github](https://github.com/ibram-reda/NavigationApp) i show you what i want to say